# How do I request a file but not save it with Wget?

Tags: linux, caching, wget

I'm using Wget to make http requests to a fresh web server.  I am doing this to warm the MySQL cache.  I do not want to save the files after they are served.

```
wget -nv -do-not-save-file $url
```

Can I do something like `-do-not-save-file` with wget?

Comment: This is a better question for Super User or Unix.SE.

Comment: as a developer I want to test a server with wget and than this question is seriously on-topic. As on-topic best answer got 142 positive votes, so this question should be reenabled as on-topic

Comment: Alternatively to -q and -O, use the flags -nd (no directory) and --delete-after.

Comment: According to the help doc(wget -h), you can use --spider option to skip download(version 1.14).

Answer (score 292, accepted):

Use `q` flag for quiet mode, and tell `wget` to output to stdout with `O-` (uppercase o) and redirect to `/dev/null` to discard the output:

`wget -qO- $url &> /dev/null`

`>` redirects application output (to a file). if `>` is preceded by ampersand, shell redirects all outputs (error and normal) to the file right of `>`. If you don't specify ampersand, then only normal output is redirected.

```
./app &>  file # redirect error and standard output to file
./app >   file # redirect standard output to file
./app 2>  file # redirect error output to file
```

if file is `/dev/null` then all is discarded.

This works as well, and simpler:

```
wget -O/dev/null -q $url
```

Comment: what do the ampersand and greater than do in this command?  can you just pipe the output to /dev/null ... wget -qO- | /dev/null ... ?

Comment: Uh, I tried this and it didn't work for me. From what I found out, the ampersand should come after the greater than symbol.

Comment: For Windows users: wget -q -O NUL http://...    Turns off logging and routes download to NUL (same as /dev/null)

Comment: wget --spider $url
Will do it.

Comment: Try this to simply throw the file away without going through stdin: `wget -P -P /dev/null`

Comment: wget -O/dev/null $url

Comment: Googlers! If you are keen on seeing header and redirect stuff (i.e. to verify your 301's, 403's etc., or well, in the OPs scenario: ensure you get 200's back…),
thus not total quiet-ness but you don't want to produce meaningless files, this is for you:  `wget http://example.com/foo/testing -O- 2>&1 | grep -E 'Location|\s20|\s30|\s40|\s50'`

Comment: You don't really need all that complicated stuff. [`wget`'s man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wget) clearly states that using `-O` is the same as redirecting output, so there's no need to go through `stdin` and redirect the output manually, you can simply do `wget -qO /dev/null $url`.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli, but you then you still need to handle the stderror?

Comment: @perreal no you don't, `-q` already takes care of that. Nothing will be printed to screen, errors included, so the only thing you need to throw to `/dev/null` is the downloaded file.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work with `-p`, i.e., you can't visit and fetch all page requisites and not save them.

Answer (score 55):

You can use `-O-` (uppercase o) to redirect content to the stdout (standard output) or to a file (even special files like `/dev/null` `/dev/stderr` `/dev/stdout` )

```
wget -O- http://yourdomain.com
```

Or:

```
wget -O- http://yourdomain.com > /dev/null
```

Or: (same result as last command)

```
wget -O/dev/null http://yourdomain.com
```

Comment: Thx, works on windows as well.

Comment: Thanks, the direct-to-/dev/null was smart, and thus the correct answer: I want the "stats output", but not the contents.

Answer (score 45):

[Curl](http://curl.haxx.se/) does that by default without any parameters or flags, I would use it for your purposes:

```
curl $url > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Curl is more about streams and wget is more about copying sites based on [this comparison](http://daniel.haxx.se/docs/curl-vs-wget.html).

Comment: Cold you explain what 2>&1 means? I get > but why the end?

Comment: @gladoscc first `>/dev/null` redirects [std out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) to /dev/null (`>/dev/null` is short for `1>/dev/null`), the second redirects [std err](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_error_.28stderr.29) to std out.

Comment: @apscience Just to add. The file descriptor for std out is 1. Shells assume std out when you leave off the descriptor from a redirect. So `>foo` is interpreted as `1>foo`.  When `&` follows a redirect, it  instructs the shell to redirect the former file descriptor to the _same output_ as the later. In this case, `2>&1` says redirect file descriptor 2 (std err) to the same place as file descriptor 1 (std out).  Since std out is already redirected to /dev/null, std err will also be redirected there. You could also write: `1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null` or `2>/dev/null >&2`.

Comment: This answer is correct, but then includes the same output redirection as the chosen answer. Simply running `curl http://www.example.com` is sufficient.