# What does this command do: 'wget -qO- 127.0.0.1'?

Tags: vagrant, wget

In the provisioning part of [vagrant guide](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/getting-started/provisioning.html), there is a command `wget -qO- 127.0.0.1` to check if apache is installed property.

Can anyone explain the command more in detail? I dont understand what the `-qO-` option does. Also, what is the meaning of `wget` to 127.0.0.1?

Thanks!

Comment: See: http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691367/how-do-i-request-a-file-but-not-save-it-with-wget

Comment: Given links are helpful. Appreciate!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dash after the `O` instructs output to go to standard output.

The `q` option means the command should be "quiet" and not write to standard output.

The two options together mean the instruction can be used nicely in a pipeline.

As far as added 127.0.0.1 as the source of the wget, that is there to make sure you have a local webserver running. Running wget on the commandline is faster than bringing up a browser.