# Trying to do a full import from the terminal. How can I grant permissions to Solr for this to work?

Tags: solr

Im trying to create a cron task to automate my Solr full imports from my database.
I was glad to find it is quite simple of a command to setup, and as shown in the image below, it works fine, except it seems I dont have write permissions.

New to Solr, and im not sure if i have to grant those permissions via the Admin or from where?
[It is connecting up to the point of executing the actual data import, then is denied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UVxjC.jpg)

Comment: It's not Solr complaining, it's `wget` attempting to save a file in the directory (`/`) where you're running the command from. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9691367/how-do-i-request-a-file-but-not-save-it-with-wget for how to avoid wget saving a file, but I'll echo the second answer on that question; use `curl` instead. Also, please don't use images for text - it makes it hard to search for the question later and people with reduced eyesight aren't able to make sense of the question.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this, I simply changed the wget to a curl in the command, and now it works. I will be careful with pictures in the future as well.